# Data structure for a priority queue of jobs with priority that changes often

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue

I have a worker class, and I can submit jobs to the worker. Worker keeps these jobs and runs them sequentially in the order of priority (priority can be any unsigned int basically). For this case std::priority_queue or even a std::set/map could be used to store jobs ordered by priority and then worker would be able to to extract them in order in O(1). Adding jobs would be O(log N).

Now, the requirement that I have is to be able to change priority of any submitted job. In case of std::set/map I'd need to remove and add back the job with different priority. This would be O(log N) and on top of that with set/map it would reallocate nodes internally afaik (this might possibly be avoided with C++17 though). What makes it unusual is that in my case I'll update job priorities way more often than scheduling or executing them. Basically I might schedule a job once, and before it's executed I may end up updating its priority thousands times. In fact, priorities of each job will be changed like 10-20 times a second.
In my case it's reasonably safe to assume that I won't have more than 10K jobs in the queue. At start of my process I expect it always to grow to 10K or so jobs and as these jobs are removed queue should eventually be almost empty all the time, and occasionally there would be 10-50 new jobs added, but it shouldn't grow more than 1000 jobs. Jobs would be removed at a rate of a few jobs a second. Because of my weird requirement of that frequent priority update std::priority_queue or a set don't seem like a good fit. Plain std::list seems to be a better choice: priority change or update/removal is O(1), and when I need to remove jobs it's O(N) to walk entire list to find highest priority item which should happen less frequently than modifying priorities.

One other observation that even though job priorities change often, these changes do not necessarily result in ordering change, e.g. I could possibly simply update key element of my set (by casting away constness or making key mutable?) if that change would still keep that modified element between left and right nodes. What would you suggest for such priority queue? Any boost container or custom data structure design is OK.

In case of set/map I use priority as a key. To make keys unique in my case each key is actually two integers: job sequence number (derived from atomic int that I increment for each new request) and actual priority number. This way if I add multiple jobs with the same priority, they will be executed in order they were scheduled, as sequence numbers would keep them ordered.

Comment: A job usually has its own `id`, so a `map<id, Node>` in which `Node = {priority->task}` seems to be a good candidate.

Comment: If the changes in priority do not result in ordering change for most of the times, won't it be better to choose the good old set/map?

Comment: @user3286661 but std::map/set do not allow changing keys, right? It would perhaps be UB

Comment: @OstrichGroomer but I do describe map or set, and clearly described what the issue with them and why plain std::list might be a better choice.

Comment: You can do that using C++17. Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract. Is there a restriction on the c++ version you use?

Comment: @user3286661 I did mention that in my question, right? I use c++11, but I'm ok to write my own impl to avoid node reallocation and handle key change without element re-ordering.

Comment: As you mentioned in the comment on the answer below, you can implement your own binary heap in that case.

Comment: @Pavel, i don't think you need to remove and add back the job with a new priority, it needs to be updated only. The cost is probably only the object copy ctor or assignment. And also removing a job is to call the job object destructor, not because the `erase` or `remove` method of your container used that is more costly, either of which usually takes constant time. You sound like your need to randomly access your data item, `std::list` I don't think is good then.

Comment: @OstrichGroomer prio obviously has to be the key of the map, otherwise why would I use map? What you wrote about { id => Node } doesn't make sense. Did I mention any ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple priority heap should fit your requirements. Insertion, removal and priority change is all O(log n). But you said usually the priority change would not result in a change in the order. So in case of a priority heap when you change the priority you would check the changed item against the parent and the 2 children and if none of the heap conditions are violated no up or down heap action is required. So only rarely the full O(log n) time will be needed. Practically it will be more like O(1).

Now for efficient operation it is crucial that given an item I you can find the position of that item in the heap in O(1) and access the parent and children.

If the heap simply contains the items in an array then that is all just pointer arithmetic. The drawback is that reordering the heap means copying the items.

If you store pointers to items in the heap then you have to also store a back reference to the position in the heap in the items them self. When you reorder the heap you then only swap the pointers and update the back references.

Comment: totally agree. Either binary heap or even list would be best (I'd need to profile to see). In my case actual job ownership is handled by another container. Priority queue for perf reasons store POD structs: prio + pointer to actual job.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your are looking for a IndexPriorityQueue. You can implement your own varient of the index priority queue based on your requirement.

A index priority queue allows you to decrease key or increase the key , i.e basically you can increase and decrease the priority of your jobs.

The following is the java implementation of the IndexMinQueue, hope it helps you. [IndexMinQueue](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html)

Comment: seems that it uses binary heap which is something that also consider using. In case if priority doesn't change ordering in binary heap I'd be able to change prio in O(1)